# Incrementing through an array in MIPs to add the contents

Tags: arrays, mips

Right now I'm trying to add up all of the contents for two arrays and storing them into their respective variables. I need to use one function for both arrays. Right now, my biggest issue is actually incrementing the array in order to actually add the contents. I moved my variables for the array, the size, and the sum into $a0, $a1, and $a2. In the fucntion, I can't find any way to increment the array to add the next value to the sum.

```
.data

array1: .word   2,4,6,8
size1:  .word   16
array2: .word   1,3,5
size2:  .word   12
sum1:   .word   0
sum2:   .word   0

.text
.globl main

main: 
lw  $a0, array1
lw  $a1, size1
lw  $a2, sum1

jal sumArr




sumArr:
beq $t0,$a1,main    # Branch to main if the size of the array and the pointer are equal

add $a2,$a2,$a0 # Add the element in the array to the corresponding sum
addi    $t0,$t0,4   # Add 4 to the pointer in order to view the next element of the array
j   sumArr
```

Is what I have so far.

Comment: post your code please by editing your question

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood how to read from memory. You should load *the address of* `array1` into `$a0` using `la`:

```
la  $a0, array1
```

`$a0` can now be said to *point to* the first element of `array1`. To read that element you would use `lw` (since each of your elements are *words*):

```
lw $t0, ($a0)
```

And to make `$a0` point to the next element you add the size of a word to `$a0`:

```
addiu $a0, $a0, 4
```

Doing another `lw $t0, ($a0)` now would give you the second element, and so on.